# OpenCL for-loop doing strange things

Tags: for-loop, opencl, noise

I'm currently implementing terrain generation in OpenCL using layered octaves of noise and I've stumbled upon this problem:

```
float multinoise2d(float2 position, float scale, int octaves, float persistence)
{
    float result = 0.0f;
    float sample = 0.0f;
    float coefficient = 1.0f;

    for(int i = 0; i < octaves; i++){
        // get a sample of a simple signed perlin noise
        sample = sgnoise2d(position/scale);

        if(i > 0){
            // Here is the problem:

            // Implementation A, this works correctly.
            coefficient = pown(persistence, i);

            // Implementation B, using this only the first
            // noise octave is visible in the terrain.
            coefficient = persistence;
            persistence = persistence*persistence;
        }

        result += coefficient * sample;
        scale /= 2.0f;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Does OpenCL parallelize for-loops, leading to synchronization issues here or am I missing something else?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: where is this code using openCL? openCL doesn't parallelize for-loops. You need to write code using thread/blocks.

Comment: @Vivek G: some OpenCL compilers can autovectorize for loops.

Comment: @Anselm: You're assuming that splitting up pown into two separate statements is a potential synchronization hazard? But pown is not an atomic function; it could have sync problems too. But like James said below, your memory is all work-item private so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem of your code is with the lines

```
coefficient = persistence;
persistence = persistence*persistence;
```

It should be changed to

```
coefficient = coefficient *persistence;
```

otherwise on every iteration

the first coeficient grows by just persistence

```
pow(persistence, 1) ; pow(persistence, 2); pow(persistence, 3) ....
```

However the second implementation goes

```
pow(persistence, 1); pow(persistence, 2); pow(persistence, 4); pow(persistence, 8) ......
```

soon "persistence" will run above the limit for float and you will get zeros (or undefined behavior) in your answer.

EDIT 
Two more things

1. Accumulation (implementation 2) is not a good idea, specially with real numbers and with algorithms that require accuracy. You might be losing a small fraction of you information every time you accumulate on "persistence" (e.g due to rounding). Prefer direct calculation (1st implementation) over accumulation whenever you can. (plus if this was Serial the 2nd implementation will be readily parallelizable.)
2. If you are working with AMD OpenCL pay attention to the pow() functions. I have had problems with those on multiple machines on multiple occasions. The functions seem to hang sometimes for no reason. Just FYI.

Comment: Basic math fail, once again. Thanks for the tips, too!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is some kind of utility method that is called in your CL kernel.  Vivek is correct in his comment above: OpenCL does not parallelize your code for you.  You have to leverage OpenCL's facilities for dividing your problem into data-parallel chunks.

Also, I don't see a potential synchronization issue in the above code.  All of your variables are in work-item private memory space.

Comment: okay, then everything is fine as I don't want to parallelize that part of the code (and can't, since persistence feedbacks). Any ideas why the iterative power doesn't work, but pown does?